# Highlighting matching nodes in Tree using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a left tree navigation with a search box on top.When the user enters some text in the Search box,the matching nodes of the tree navigation should get highlighted.
I want to do it using Java script,Can anyone point me to any such examples or documentation for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any html etc can't really see what your setup is! But I assume you want something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/cwc66a3d/3/

Use indexOf to find any matching cases among the options, then using the position given, insert a span to contain the matching text with a yellow background to give the impression of highlighting.

The timeout is simply because of delays in event firing, sure to make sure it highlights in real time it is needed.

```
document.onkeydown = function () {
    setTimeout(function () { //delay so can take the event fire into account
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName('tree');
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i].innerHTML = list[i].innerText;
            var pos = (list[i].innerHTML).indexOf(s.value);
            if (s.value !== '' && pos != -1) {
                var a = list[i].innerHTML.substring(0, pos) + '<span style="background: yellow;">' + list[i].innerHTML.substring(pos,1+ (list[i].innerHTML).indexOf(s.value.substr(s.value.length-1, 1))) + '</span>' + (list[i].innerHTML).substring(1+ (list[i].innerHTML).indexOf(s.value.substr(s.value.length-1, 1)), (list[i].innerHTML).length);
                list[i].innerHTML = a;
            }
        }
    }, 50);
};
```